# How to set the main title for the apriori rules plot in the grouped method (R)?

Tags: r, plot, apriori, arules

The plot method for apriori rules when used like this below should print the title, but its not. What is the right way to set the plot title?

```
plot(rules, method='grouped', control=list(main='My Title'))
```

Here is the plot, see the title is 'Grouped matrix for 61 rules', it is not setting my title correctly.
[image]

Comment: have i misunderstood your question? I am not sure if what i answered is what you were asking for in the  1st place..

Comment: @Gopalakrishna: You are right to be confused. The `arulesViz` package clearly states that what you are doing should work and that's the only way to influence the `main` title. I think you'll need to file a bug or take a look at the source to the `arulesViz` package and try to make a modification there. (I tried it with the `AdultUCI` data set using latest `arules` & `arulesViz` packages under R 3.0.3)

Comment: Thanks hrbrmstr. I guess it worked for you. May be some bug then.

Answer (score 0):

Too late but for the newcomers this works.

```
plot(rules, method='grouped', main='My Title')
```